# Make jqGrid add button direct to new page

Tags: c#, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I just got jqGrid working on my site and I am using the built in navGrid but I can not figure out how to make the add button go to a new page when clicked instead of a pop up page. I did a bit of searching but could not find anything. My current JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    $( '#Sections' ).jqGrid( {
        url: '/Admin/Section/GridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'RouteName', 'Title'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'RouteName', index: 'RouteName', align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', align: 'left' }
        ],
        pager: $( '#SectionsPager' ),
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'ID',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true
    } ).navGrid(
       '#SectionsPager',
       //enabling buttons
       { add: true, del: false, edit: false, search: false },
       //edit options
       { width: 'auto' },
       //add options
       { width: 'auto', url: '/Admin/Section/Add' },
       //delete options
       {} );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the creator of jqGrid you can not modify the default add button but you can add a custom button that would redirect to a new page.

Source: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/make-add-button-on-navigation-redirect-to-new-page/

Answer (score -1):

Try this (assuming your add button id is "add_list")

```
$("#add_list").click(function() {
    document.location = "http://google.com";
});
```

Comment: I am not making an add button. jqGrid generates it as part of the .navGrid function